# Python GeraldoReports - Format a summed value with commas

Tags: python, django, geraldo

I'm using Geraldo Reports to create PDF reports for my Django project.  I am stuck on how to format values that are summary values.
I have an ObjectValue with `action=FIELD_ACTION_SUM` in a report group. I can't figure out how to format the returned value as a number with commas to separate the thousands.

I tried the get_text argument, which is listed in Geraldo Reports documentation, but not documented well on how to use it.

My current ObjectValue:

```
ObjectValue(
  attribute_name='labor',
  action=FIELD_ACTION_SUM,
  left=7 * inch,
  width=.8 * inch,
  style={'alignment': TA_RIGHT},
  get_text=lambda instance, value: '{:,.2f}'.format(value),
  stores_text_in_cache=False
),
```

I haven't had any luck searching for solutions.  Does anyone here know what I'm doing wrong, or what I should be doing instead?

Comment: I tried Geraldo Report but you can't put commas. I like there reporting format but there's lot of limitation.

Comment: anything else you found to make PDF reports *easily* with django/python?

Comment: No, I end up creating my own reports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer after much trial and error ! In my example I have a field in a queryset called 'jd_gross' which I want to total in my report....I finally abandoned the  action=FIELD_ACTION_SUM section and rolled my own

in my band_detail section I can display this field with commas with the following :

```
        ObjectValue(attribute_name='jd_gross', left=26.7*cm, width=1.7*cm, style={'alignment':TA_RIGHT}, get_value=lambda instance: intcomma(instance.jd_gross)),
```

The answer that works for me for the summary section however is to add to the :
    def **init**(self, *args, **kwargs):
section, after the :
        self.band_page_header.elements += [
I used the same concept to calculate my total, convert it to a formatted string and add a line as a System Field in to my summary section as follows :

```
    myset = self.queryset
    grosstotal = 0
    for myline in myset:
        if myline.jd_gross:
            grosstotal += myline.jd_gross
    ugrosstotal = intcomma(grosstotal)
    self.band_summary.elements += [
        SystemField(expression=ugrosstotal, top=1*cm, left=26.5*cm, width=1.9*cm, style={'alignment':TA_RIGHT}),
        ]
```

so my complete inherited report is now as follows :

class JobdetailsReport(DefaultReport):
    title = 'Job Details'
    page_size = landscape(A4)

```
class band_detail(DetailBand):
    height=0.7*cm
    elements=[
        ObjectValue(attribute_name='jd_job', left=0.1*cm),
        ObjectValue(attribute_name='c_name', left=1.5*cm),
        ObjectValue(attribute_name='clientname', left=5.8*cm),
        ObjectValue(attribute_name='jd_return', left=10.1*cm),
        ObjectValue(attribute_name='jd_delivery', left=12.6*cm),
        ObjectValue(attribute_name='get_j_status1_display', left=15.1*cm),
        ObjectValue(attribute_name='get_j_status2_display', left=17.6*cm),
        ObjectValue(attribute_name='jd_prodref', left=20.1*cm),
        ObjectValue(attribute_name='userformalname', left=23*cm),
        ObjectValue(attribute_name='jd_gross', left=26.7*cm, width=1.7*cm, style={'alignment':TA_RIGHT}, get_value=lambda instance: intcomma(instance.jd_gross)),
        ]
    borders = {'bottom': True}

class band_summary(ReportBand):
    height = 1.7*cm
    elements = [
        Label(text='Records printed:', top=1*cm, left=0.5*cm),
        ObjectValue(expression='count(jd_job)', top=1*cm, left=5.6*cm),
        Label(text="Total Value:", top=1*cm, left=22*cm),
        ]
    borders = {'top': True}

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(JobdetailsReport, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.band_page_header.elements += [
        Label(text="Job No.", top=0.8*cm, left=0.1*cm),
        Label(text="Client", top=0.8*cm, left=1.5*cm),
        Label(text="Delivery", top=0.8*cm, left=5.8*cm),
        Label(text="Return", top=0.8*cm, left=10.1*cm),
        Label(text="Delivery", top=0.8*cm, left=12.6*cm),
        Label(text="Physical Status", top=0.8*cm, left=15.1*cm),
        Label(text="Accts Status", top=0.8*cm, left=17.6*cm),
        Label(text="Reference", top=0.8*cm, left=20.1*cm),
        Label(text="Our Contact", top=0.8*cm, left=23*cm),
        Label(text="Gross", top=0.8*cm, left=27*cm),
        ]

    myset = self.queryset
    grosstotal = 0
    for myline in myset:
        if myline.jd_gross:
            grosstotal += myline.jd_gross
    ugrosstotal = intcomma(grosstotal)
    self.band_summary.elements += [
        SystemField(expression=ugrosstotal, top=1*cm, left=26.5*cm, width=1.9*cm, style={'alignment':TA_RIGHT}),
        ]
```

Hope that helps you ! It only took me several hours to get it to work......